# Dynamics 365: why an assemby was found for real-time workflow but wosn't for the same background workflow?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

Dynamics 365 On-Premises, version 2014 (9.1.3.11)
.Net Framework 4.6.2
NuGet-package: `Microsoft.CrmSdk.Workflow version 9.0.2.46`

I created some `CodeActivity` and use it in my Process. If the workflow is *real-time* then it works fine. But if I convert it to *background* workflow then I get an Exception when it works:

> could not load file or assemby `System.Text.Json Version=5.0.0.2`

What is the reason of such behaviour can be? Why was the assembly successfully found in the first case, but wasn't in the second?

Comment: Does your deployment consist of multiple servers? The server handling the async processes probably does not have the proper .NET Framework version installed or you have an issue with 32 vs. 64 bit?

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen our dev server is single instance. I solved the problem by Costura.Fody using.